# Automate google earth screenshot

Tags: python, matlab, api, screenshot

Currently I use google earth to do the following:

1) load a .kml file in google earth

2) zoom/pan in google earth to view particular portion of data from .kml file
   - this essentially comes down to specifying a latitude range and longitude range because I always want North to be pointing to top of screen and the camera to be looking straight down the altitude vector

3) Print Screen the view I want

4) Copy clipboard into irfanview, crop everything out but the earth part (remove toolbars, etc)

4) Save image as .png

Is there any way to automate this process? Specifically, I need to automate opening google earth to a .kml file, specify a lat/long range and screenshot the view. I'm most experienced with Matlab and python, but I'm willing to learn anything that could make this a process that is completed entirely with code.

Thanks.

Comment: I would say this is probably violating a terms of use agreement.

Comment: Java can be used directly from your matlab command line, so take a closer look at this https://code.google.com/p/gwt-earth-3/